# Is this Mac SDK can run in iOS App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, sdk, macros

SDK is NDI.

[SDK download link](http://new.tk/NDISDKV2APPLE)

I try to use Swift and Objective-c to add .a file and .h file.

and import .h file name to header file.

but xcode give a lot of issues.

is it mean this SDK can't run in iOS project?

[This is error screen screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFBZm.png)

Comment: What are the errors? If it's built only for MacOS platform, it won't work for iOS.

Comment: Has been added the issues screensot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the download and there indeed seems iOS support.

Add the `.h` files in the `NDI SDK for Apple/include/` plus the `NDI SDK for Apple/lib/iOS/libndi_ios.a` to your project.

Then add `libndi_ios.a` to your Xcode target's Build Phases > Link Binary With Libraries.

Comment: thank you , I had try to do what you say, it work , but still give issue.